How do I bind/combine selected columns from multiple dataframes into one
I have many data.frames (448) with the same columns names (9 in total), like this:
       V1              V2      V4    ... V9
ENSG00000000003.15   TSPAN6   7095
ENSG00000000005.6     TNMD    4355
       .                .       .
       .                .       .

i want to create another data.frame, maintaining the first 2 columns (V1 and V2), these are identical in every data.frame, and merge V4 column (these are different for every data.frame) from all data.frames, the rest of the columns should be excluded.
If it could be possible, I would like to rename the V4 columns to "sample1", "sample2" and so on, until 448.
So the final dataframe should be:
       V1              V2     V4_1    V4_2 ... V4_448
ENSG00000000003.15   TSPAN6   7095    3856       .
ENSG00000000005.6     TNMD    4355    2976       .
       .                .       .      .         . 
       .                .       .      .         .

I already did this:
reader <- function(f){
  read.table(f, sep='\t', skip=6, header=FALSE)
}

files <- list.files(path, 
                    recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE)

myfilelist <- lapply(files, reader)

But I don't know how to combine only these selected columns
This is the output of dput(lapply(myfilelist[1:2], head)):
myfilelist <- list(structure(list(V1 = c("ENSG00000000003.15", "ENSG00000000005.6", 
"ENSG00000000419.13", "ENSG00000000457.14", "ENSG00000000460.17", 
"ENSG00000000938.13"), V2 = c("TSPAN6", "TNMD", "DPM1", "SCYL3", 
"C1orf112", "FGR"), V3 = c("protein_coding", "protein_coding", 
"protein_coding", "protein_coding", "protein_coding", "protein_coding"
), V4 = c(7094L, 2L, 4355L, 1149L, 372L, 585L), V5 = c(3573L, 
1L, 2201L, 953L, 553L, 281L), V6 = c(3521L, 1L, 2154L, 883L, 
579L, 308L), V7 = c(59.9764, 0.052, 138.3704, 6.4018, 2.3896, 
6.6335), V8 = c(20.5827, 0.0178, 47.4859, 2.197, 0.8201, 2.2765
), V9 = c(22.2037, 0.0192, 51.2256, 2.37, 0.8847, 2.4558)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(V1 = c("ENSG00000000003.15", 
"ENSG00000000005.6", "ENSG00000000419.13", "ENSG00000000457.14", 
"ENSG00000000460.17", "ENSG00000000938.13"), V2 = c("TSPAN6", 
"TNMD", "DPM1", "SCYL3", "C1orf112", "FGR"), V3 = c("protein_coding", 
"protein_coding", "protein_coding", "protein_coding", "protein_coding", 
"protein_coding"), V4 = c(2616L, 23L, 3746L, 1288L, 510L, 1578L
), V5 = c(1369L, 9L, 1876L, 1015L, 681L, 797L), V6 = c(1250L, 
14L, 1871L, 984L, 693L, 782L), V7 = c(16.8063, 0.4541, 90.4417, 
5.4531, 2.4895, 13.5969), V8 = c(4.8615, 0.1314, 26.1617, 1.5774, 
0.7201, 3.9331), V9 = c(6.0158, 0.1625, 32.3733, 1.9519, 0.8911, 
4.867)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame"))


It would be helpful if you provided a reproducible example. You can add data to your post that is accessible to us by using the dput() command. For example, copy-paste the output of dput(lapply(myfilelist[1:2], head)), which will give the first six rows of your first two data frames.

I updated the question, check if its better

It's not clear to me how you want to join this list of data frames (are the first two columns identical?), but here is an option using left-join:
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

imap(myfilelist, \(df, i) select(df, 1:2, "sample{i}" := 4) ) |>
  reduce(left_join, by = join_by(V1, V2))

If the first two columns are identical across all data frames then you could bind them together:
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

bind_cols(myfilelist[[1]][1:2],
          imap(myfilelist, \(df, i) select(df, "sample{i}" := 4)) |> bind_cols())


sorry for the mistake, the first 2 columns are identical in every dataframe, but I want to join V4 columns, which are different in every dataframe

@Camila That's an easy fix -- the 3 represented the column index. I simply updated this to 4 for the fourth column as you requested. If the first two columns are identical, then both these solutions should produce the same output, though you might want to use the second solution just to be safe.

We can do this quite easily in base R as well
bound <- data.frame(myfilelist[[1]][1:2], do.call(cbind, lapply(myfilelist, "[", 4)))
colnames(bound)[-(1:2)] <- paste0("sample", seq(length(myfilelist)))
bound
#                   V1       V2 sample1 sample2
# 1 ENSG00000000003.15   TSPAN6    7094    2616
# 2  ENSG00000000005.6     TNMD       2      23
# 3 ENSG00000000419.13     DPM1    4355    3746
# 4 ENSG00000000457.14    SCYL3    1149    1288
# 5 ENSG00000000460.17 C1orf112     372     510
# 6 ENSG00000000938.13      FGR     585    1578

